# Unrecognized selector error with TableViews and segues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am writing an iOS app and I have a problem. I have three classes. In the first class, I use a segue to go to the second view, and I need to transfer data from the first class to the second one. That's why I used:

```
 @IBSegueAction func goToSearchBar(_ coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
    currentCountry = countries[index]
    return SearchBar(coder: coder, selectedRegion: currentCountry)
}
```

And I had to implement the following in the next class:

```
init?(coder: NSCoder, selectedRegion: String) {
      self.selectedRegion = selectedRegion
      super.init(coder: coder)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Then, on the second class, I want to use a TableView. Thus, I connected the TableView from the Storyboard to that class, and created another class for the cells:

```
class MovieCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!


  init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
  }

  override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
  }
```

}

I connected all the outlets. When I try to run the code however, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file .../MovieCell.swift, line 19
```

To correct this, I modified the required init? function with:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

But then I get the error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-
      [UIImageView _isSymbolImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7fcf823300'
 terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
 CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 12 (58C5441D-67DD-4DF1-B603-B491641C816A) -
 Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone 12
```

I have made sure that I connected all the outlets and that there were no missing connections.
I would appreciate some help.

Comment: You can remove both of the `init` methods from your cell class. Just inherit from `UITableviewCell`

Comment: "have made sure that I connected all the outlets and that there were no missing connections" I doubt it. If you'd like to post the project to GitHub I'll take a look at it for you, but it is almost certainly an incorrect outlet connection.